# Vue Js Not appearing on blade

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I was trying to implement vue js on my recent project as I'm new to it i may be do something error which i couldn't catch.I'm writing the steps i followed to make my component work. if you find any error.hope you'll help me to sort this out.

this is my blade view:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                   <chat inline-template>

                        You are logged in!

                        <hr>

                        <h2>Write something to all users</h2>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="something" required="required" v-model="newMsg" @keyup.enter="press">            

                        <hr>
                        <h3>Messages</h3>

                        <ul v-for="post in posts">
                       <b>@{{ post.username }} says:</b> @{{ post.message }}</li>    
                        </ul>
                     </chat>
                </div>
```

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
Vue.component('chat', require('./components/chat.vue')); 

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**this is my chat.vue**

```
<script>
module.exports = {

    data() {
        return {
            posts: [],
            newMsg: '',

        }
    },


    ready() {
        Echo.channel('public-test-channel')
            .listen('ChatMessageWasReceived', (data) => {

                // Push ata to posts list.
                this.posts.push({
                    message: data.chatMessage.message,
                    username: data.user.name
                });
            });
    },

    methods: {

        press() {

            // Send message to backend.
            this.$http.post('/message/', {message: this.newMsg})
                .then((response) => {

                    // Clear input field.
                    this.newMsg = '';
                });
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

when i load my view, I saw nothing on it. means blank page. what could be possible Error ? Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your element with the id app? are there any console errors? what is the http response code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a app div around the component:

```
<div id ="app">
    <chat>

    </chat>
</div>
```

This is where the Vue application will be created.

Mick